# Have a new conversion operator without modify sources

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I have two classes **Dot** and **Point** that does exactly the same thing.
They just came from two different libraries and I have to use them both.

I want to be able to do:

```
Dot d;
Point p = d;

std::map<Dot, int> m;
m[p] = 1;
```

I cannot modify the libraries source code.

My Idea was to add some operators in my implementation... but I am missing something and I cannot have my code compiling.

I just have many

```
error: prototype for 'void Dot::operator=(const Point&)' 
    does not match any in class....
```

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Replace `m[p]` with `m[d]`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a new implicit conversion between classes `A` and `B` unless you are allowed to modify either `A` or `B`. If you're really desperate, you could make a new class `C` that has converting constructors from and conversion operators to both `A` and `B`, and use that as the key type for `m`...

Answer (score 3):

You could just have a new class with two contructors, one for accepting dots and one for accepting points, and build an new object from them.